# How to automatically execute FreeAndNill() after thread termination

Tags: delphi

At the moment I'm using additional thread to nicely free memory after thread.
Before you ask. No I can't use FreeOnTerminate:=true because I need .waitfor.
I also need FreeAndNil() because only in this way I can check if thread is running using Assigned(). Example code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  

  SupervisorThread:= TSupervisorThread.Create(True);
  SupervisorThread.FreeOnTerminate:=false; //MUST BE FALSE!
  SupervisorThread.Priority := tpNormal;
  SupervisorThread.Resume;

end;

procedure TSupervisorThread.Execute;
begin

  CleaningThread:= TCleaningThread.Create(True);
  CleaningThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  CleaningThread.Priority := tpNormal;
  CleaningThread.Resume;

  //some loops here

end;

procedure TCleaningThread.Execute;
begin

  if Assigned(SupervisorThread)=true then
  begin
    SupervisorThread.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(SupervisorThread);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin

  if Assigned(SupervisorThread)=false then CanClose:=true  
  else 
  begin
    CanClose:=false;
    ShowMessage('Cannot close form because SiupervisorThread is still working'); 
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Use events to signal, er, events

Comment: If the only thing you want is to know if the thread is complete, assign an `OnTerminate` handler to the thread.

Comment: I must point out that a thread that starts out blocked by another thread with `SupervisorThread.WaitFor;` seems a little pointless as a thread. Remember the point of threads is to allow code to execute _concurrently_. Your example begs the questions: Why can't you just run Cleaning at the end of Supervisor? Why do you have to create the Cleaning object up front; can't you wait until Supervisor is done? What happens if you want to `Terminate` Cleaning? - you can't because it's not in a `while not Terminated` loop.

Comment: "What happens if you want to Terminate Cleaning? - you can't because it's not in a while not Terminated loop"
CleaningThread is automatically terminated and freed when SupervisorThread is terminated. I do not see any problem here. 

"Why can't you just run Cleaning at the end of Supervisor? "
Where exactly? Inside the thread?

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera:  In the supervisor's `OnTerminate` event, or even in its `DoTerminate()` virtual method.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera ***Of course*** you'd do it inside the Supervisor thread (at the end to be specific). That thread is no longer needed for anything else. A thread doesn't have anything special that either prevents or requires: "more code to run before its done". In fact, one of the major benefits of putting a call to Cleaning code inside the thread is that you can use a **try..finally** to protect whatever resource needs cleaning and _guarantee_ it gets called.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event:

```
private
  procedure DoTerminateEvent(Sender: TObject);

var
  isRunning: Boolean;

procedure TForm2.DoTerminateEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  isRunning := False;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if (isRunning) then
  begin
    CanClose := false;
    ShowMessage('Cannot close form because SupervisorThread is still working')
  end else
    CanClose := true;
end;
```

Set the `OnTerminate` handler when creating the Thread:

```
SupervisorThread := TSupervisorThread.Create(True);
...
SupervisorThread.OnTerminate := DoTerminateEvent;
SupervisorThread.Resume;
```

Or, pass it as a parameter to the Thread's constructor:

```
TSupervisorThread = class(TThread)
public
  constructor Create(OnTerminatEvent: TNotifyEvent);
end;

procedure TThreadCustom.Create(OnTerminateEvent: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  OnTerminate := OnTerminateEvent;
end;
```

```
SupervisorThread := TSupervisorThread.Create(DoTerminateEvent);
```

Comment: My delphi says "NOT ENOUGH ACTUAL PARAMETERS" here
SupervisorThread.OnTerminate:=(DoTerminateEvent);

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera That's because the code in the question is wrong. If you would read the documentation, and think a little about it, you'd be able to work out what was wrong. Don't stop trying to think for yourself.

Comment: I tried before without brackets but I got
"INCOMPATIBLE TYPES: 'method pointer and regular procedure'

Comment: `DoTerminateEvent()` must be a non-static method of a class.

Comment: @strykerbits: there were a ton of typos in your code. I have fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event to detect when a thread has finished running, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  if not Assigned(SupervisorThread) then
  begin
    SupervisorThread:= TSupervisorThread.Create(True);
    SupervisorThread.FreeOnTerminate := False;
    SupervisorThread.Priority := tpNormal;
    SupervisorThread.OnTerminate := SupervisorThreadTerminated;
    SupervisorThread.Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SupervisorThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SupervisorThread := nil;
end;
```

However, this creates some problems.  It creates a race condition, since the cleaning thread acts on the `SupervisorThread` pointer, which could disappear at any time while the cleaning thread is still running.  And it creates a memory leak, as you still need to free the `SupervisorThread` object after it has terminated, but you can't do that in the `OnTerminate` handler directly.

A better solution would not rely on the `SupervisorThread` pointer at all.

```
var
  SupervisorTerminated: TEvent;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SupervisorTerminated := TEvent.Create(nil, True, True, '');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(SupervisorThread) then
  begin
    SupervisorThread.Terminate;
    while SupervisorTerminated.WaitFor(1000) = wrTimeout do
      CheckSynchronize;
  end;
  SupervisorTerminated.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  if not Assigned(SupervisorThread) then
  begin
    SupervisorThread := TSupervisorThread.Create(True);
    SupervisorThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    SupervisorThread.Priority := tpNormal;
    SupervisorThread.OnTerminate := SupervisorThreadTerminated;
    SupervisorTerminated.ResetEvent;
    SupervisorThread.Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SupervisorThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SupervisorThread := nil;
  SupervisorTerminated.SetEvent;
end;
```

```
procedure TCleaningThread.Execute;
begin
  SupervisorTerminated.WaitFor(INFINITE);
end;
```

```
procedure TForm2.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := (SupervisorTerminated.WaitFor(0) = wrSignaled);
  if not CanClose then
    ShowMessage('Cannot close form because Supervisor Thread is still working'); 
end;
```